# Need to pull data from MySQL data base using PHP to read dynamic checkboxes

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox, dynamic, html-table

I am trying to pull data from mysql table using dynamic checkboxes created previously, however it looks like my search only displays 2 records max and if I select more than 3 checkboxes it will not return anything, so I was wondering if someone could help me figure out how to do it.

Below is my code, I really appreciate your help:

```
$warehouse = @$_POST['wh'];
switch($button){
    case 'Submit':
    if(@$_POST['wh']){
    $warehouse = @$_POST['wh'];
    $length = count($warehouse);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++){
    //echo '<br>'.$warehouse[$i];


                }                           

                $consult = "SELECT * FROM contact_info WHERE ";
                for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++){
                    $consult = $consult . "warehouse='$warehouse[$i]'";
                    if(!$i+1 == $length){
                        $consult = $consult . " OR ";
                    }

                }
                echo '<br>'.$length.'<br>';
                print_r ($consult);
                $response = mysqli_query($connection, $consult);
            if($response){
                    $registry = mysqli_affected_rows($connection);

            if($registry > 1){                      
                    echo '<br><table width="800" align="center" border="2" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">
                            <form action="index.php" method="post" >
                                <tr>
                                    <td align="center"><strong>Warehouse</strong></td>
                                    <td align="center"><strong>Name</strong></td>
                                    <td align="center"><strong>Lastname</strong></td>
                                    <td align="center"><strong>Phone</strong></td>
                                    <td align="center"><strong>I-net</strong></td>
                                    <td align="center"><strong>E-mail</strong></td>
                                </tr>';

                while($registry = mysqli_fetch_array($response, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
                    echo '<form action="index.php" method=post >    
                            <tr>
                                <td div align="center">'.$registry['warehouse'].'
                                <td div align="center">'.$registry['name'].'
                                <td div align="center">'.$registry['lastname'].'
                                <td div align="center">'.$registry['phone'].'
                                <td div align="center">'.$registry['inet'].'
                                <td div align="center">'.$registry['email'].'
                            </tr>';


                                        }
                                        echo '</form>';
                                    echo '
                                    </form>
                            </table>';
```

Comment: **DO NOT** ever put `$_POST` data directly in a query, it's extremely hazardous and creates a [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). You should be using prepared statements and the [`bind_param`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) method to add data to your query.

Comment: thanks for the comment tadman, but that doesn't really help me solve my problem, would you have a suggestion on how to pull this data from mysql using checkboxes?

Comment: Part of the problem is you're building an application using raw PHP and aren't using a [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) which would handle check-box data seamlessly. If you go your own way, you have to re-invent the wheel every time. In your question I don't even see an `<input>` element to comment on.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for the link to the development framework, I've read some good information and for me this is all new (just self-learning), believe me, I am taking note of your suggestions. Can I ask, how do you suggest me to pull the data out of mysql with my check box selection? Again, I am really new at this (trying to learn by myself) so I little script wouldn't hurt. Really appreciate your help.

Comment: I'm not even sure where the checkbox is supposed to go or where it's coming from. What you're doing here is rather unconventional and hard to follow. If you're intending to put this on the public internet, there's some extremely serious problems with it that would make that a huge liability. Re-writing it using the conventions of a framework while annoying is the best way to get the desired result: A working, maintainable application that can't get hacked in two seconds.

Comment: Thanks tadman, I found my answer on another post, really appreciate your time trying to help me, I really appreciated as I am new on this (trying to learn by myself)

Comment: Good to hear you got it. Have a look at a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://phptherightway.com/) if you're new to PHP and want to know more about best practices. The web is filled with dangerously obsolete examples that are best avoided.